# price movement of 2 candles in raport with ATR

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I get this error on my code

Mismatched input 'alert' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

I want  to make an alert when the price from 2 candles moves more than 1 ATR

```
my_atr = at(14)

if (close - open[1] > my_atr )
  alert("bull case",  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
else
 alert("bear case",  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pine there are very strict requirements for indentation four spaces or tabulation

```
if (close - open[1] > my_atr )
    alert("bull case",  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
else
    alert("bear case",  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: Use the recommendations of the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)